# Getting Java.text.ParseException while using ExtentReports with Selenium

Tags: selenium, testng

I am trying to use ExtentReports with Selenium Webdriver and Testng for graphical reporting.

Currently I am using version 2.40.0 of same. But I am getting below exception when set replaceExisting value to false viz.

```
ExtentReports extentnew = new ExtentReports("D:\\ExtentReports\\myreport1.html", false);
```

Kindly assist on same.

**Exception :**

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.utils.DateTimeUtil.getDate(DateTimeUtil.java:22)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.converters.TestConverter.createTestList(TestConverter.java:58)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:91)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.<init>(ExtentReports.java:213)
    at AdvanceReporting.<init>(AdvanceReporting.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
    at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:186)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:160)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:141)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:271)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

Comment: can you share your code, error says it isn't able to parse the date. Can you check date format.

Comment: In your previous run, there must be some errors because it is saying the date is empty.  Did you change any settings in the config.xml file?

Comment: Can you add the code?  Why are you appending to report if you plan to use the merge tool?  Just use true to replace report.

Comment: @Karthik , if I replace the report how can I use merge tool. Because it will override existing report.

Comment: You can create another report with different name.

Comment: @Karthik , Do I have to change file name every time in code before execution to have different reports?

Comment: I use a timestamp like ReportMMddyyyyHhmmss for testing.  For my prod executions, a new folder gets ceated and everything gets stored there so its always dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

This exception was thrown because I was missing endTest() statement in one of the test method and trying to append result in already created report in second run. It is now working after inserting endTest().

Thank you

Comment: Could you please be more specific? where did you exactly added endTest() and where endTest() come from?